# Konva Text Edit option without using textarea

Tags: konvajs

I have recently started using konva library for one of our projects, I am trying to add text on stage and edit same without using a textarea.

Suppose I want to edit text on stage I will just want to edit it on a click of the seleted text. When I click it should directly make the cursor blinking for input.

I have ref below konva example but it uses textarea popup to edit.
[example](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Editable_Text.html#stq=&stp=0)
https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Editable_Text.html#stq=&stp=0

Comment: Your other option would be a contentEditable div, but that would still require the use of an HTML element similar to the textarea solution proposed by @lavrton.  If you are seeking a rich text solution then you need to consider a plugin that provides rich text for editing, then a means to capture a snapshot of the html produced into an image and render that to the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it with Konva without a textarea. But you can make the textarea looks and feel like you edit the canvas. You just need to match CSS styles as close to canvas rendering as possible. So users will not notice that there is the textarea.